# Вывод матрицы без нулей

Tags: c, массивы, матрицы

Составить программу, которая выводит матрицу, образованную из исходной матрицы путем вычеркивания из нее всех строк и столбцов, содержащих хотя бы один нулевой элемент.

Например есть матрица:

```
1 2 4 5 6
2 3 0 4 1
0 1 1 4 2
2 4 1 4 5
```

Итог:

```
2 5 6
3 4 1
4 4 5
```

Comment: В чем заключаются ваши затруднения?

Comment: каким образом "вычеркнуть" эти строки и столбцы, чтобы получить результат?

Comment: Ну скорее всего вам надо скопировать данные в новую матрицу, но без таких строк и столбцов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так, правда плохо знаком `C` написал на `JS`, алгоритм тот же и все закоментил пошагово

```js
let a = [
 [1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
 [6,  0,  0,  9,  10],
 [11, 0,  0,  0,  15],
 [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
 [21, 22, 23, 0,  25],
]
print(a);

let bY = [];//Массив в который будет записано положение 0 в столбцах


for(let i=a.length-1; i>=0; i--){
 del = false; // ключ на удаление строки после перебора всех ее элементов
 for(let j=0; j<a[i].length; j++){
  if(!a[i][j]){
   del = true;
   bY[j] = 1;
  }else{
   if(bY[j]!==1)
    bY[j] = 0;
  }
 }
 if(del) a.splice(i, 1); //удаление строки
}
// bY = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0];

for(let j=bY.length-1; j>=0; j--){
 if(!bY[j]) continue;
    for(let i=0; i<a.length; i++){
  a[i].splice(j, 1);
    }
}

print(a);

function print(arr){
let aq = document.getElementById("a");
    for(let i=0; i<a.length; i++){
      for(let j=0; j<a[i].length; j++){
        aq.innerHTML+=a[i][j]+"\t";
      }
     aq.innerHTML+="\n";
  }
  aq.innerHTML+="<hr>";
}
```

```html
<pre id="a"><hr></pre>
```

Comment: Похоже на правду, но там ошибка. В первой строке правильно удалило: 2 4 5, а последняя строка 14 15 16, должна быть 14 16 17 ((

Comment: @RomanBenko не заметил сразу, исправил теперь все как надо))